# Macbook Pro turning off in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, high-sierra

Since upgrading to the latest MacOS my Macbook Pro seems to be turning off while in sleep mode if left for a long time, *I think* only when it's not plugged in.

If I close the lid and open it up in about 10 mins, it'll come out of sleep as expected and ask for my password. However if I close the lid and leave it for a few hours, I need to press the power button to boot it back up again asks for HDD encryption password and then prompts to log in.

I have tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC but no luck. There are no further MacOS updates.

Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please add the exact model of MBP you have trouble with and the OS version.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13", Early 2015) and macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.1.

Comment: How much battery does it have when you boot it back up?

Comment: Same as before, doesn't go down. I've just removed Beta versions from the AppStore and installed back to 10.13 incase the newest beta version caused it.

Comment: I'm on 10.13.1 public release and I have this issue with my 2016 15"! Every morning I have to hit the power button. I'm not sure if being on battery power affects it, but it's often at about 85% when I turn it on so idk why it would shut down automatically.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Check out my answer below. Is a bug in 10.13.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was down to public beta 10.13.1.
My fix was to turn off beta downloads from the App Store, download High Sierra from the App Store and install as normal. Seems to have corrected the behaviour.

Comment: I don’t believe I’m running public betas, I could be mistaken, but I generally only run betas on my iPhone. Is it an issue with no beta releases of 10.13.1 as well?

Answer (score 1):

My iMac began shutting down at random in sleep mode. As it was 6 years old I assumed that the power supply was packing up causing overheating and shut down.

Was about to rush out and buy a new one but had a specialist look at it first. It turned out to be software,  freebie malware and avast. Once removed machine runs fast,like new, and doe not shut down. Object lesson look before you leap!